# Is there a way to interface with Python's SpaCy using Haskell?

Tags: python, haskell, nlp, spacy

I've read a little about Haskell's foreign function interface, FFI, and it seems like it can call Python functions, but can it do something complicated, like parse a document using SpaCy, and then access all that document's properties in Haskell? If so, what would that look like?

Comment: I think this question is a bit too broad. SpaCy seems to be a quite high level library, thus wrapping its features with the FFI will be a tedious task if possible at all - in addition you try to marry a dynamicly typed language with a strong & static one which is already a task to do.

Comment: That'll be interesting to see Haskell with SpaCy =)

Comment: I do believe that it's possible to wrap SpaCy into some sort of API request that it's curl-able but that'll take a significant work to make sure that all functionalities are API accessible.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit late to the party, but nowadays there a number of out of the box options for setting up SpaCy as an API, as described by alvas which do the trick rather nicely. eg. https://github.com/microsoft/cookiecutter-spacy-fastapi